# Reusable slim with parameters?

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

I have a date partial as follows, which is hardcoded at the moment:

```
#postdate
  .grid
    .grid__cell.day 15th
    .grid__cell.month Jan
    .grid__cell.year 2015
```

However, is there a way to make this reusable by making the date dynamic so that I can pass in the date from another slim file?

I'm not sure how to go about this since you render the partial just by adding `== slim :'components/_date'`. Is there a better way of doing this sort of thing altogether?

I'm using Ruby with sass and sinatra.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...is there a way to make this reusable by making the date dynamic so
>   that I can pass in the date...

In a sinatra route, you can set variables, which are accessible in your slim templates:

routes.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim'

get '/' do
  @day = 170000   #****HERE****
  slim :index
end
```

views/index.slim:

```
h2 This is views/index.slim:

div The day is: #{@day}  #****HERE****

ul.fruit
  li Apples
  li Oranges


== slim :'components/_date'
```

views/components/_date.slim:

```
#postdate
  .grid
    .grid__cell.day  =@day  #****HERE*****
    .grid__cell.month Jan
    .grid__cell.year 2015
```

I don't really understand what you mean by:

> pass in the date from another slim file

Can you provide an example of what you want to do?

**Response to comment:**

According to the Sinatra faq, [How do I render partials?](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#partials), if you want to render a partial and specify local variables for the partial, you need to install a gem:

```
$ gem install sinatra-partial
```

Here is an example app:

```
~/sinatra_projects$ tree slim_app/

slim_app/
├── models
├── public
│   ├── cool_stuff.html
│   └── imgs
├── routes.rb
└── views
    ├── components
    │   └── _date.slim
    ├── index.slim
    └── layout.slim
```

routes.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim'

#***NEW STUFF:
require 'sinatra/partial' 
set :partial_template_engine, :slim  
enable :partial_underscores

get '/' do
  slim :index
end
```

views/components/index.slim:

```
h2 This is views/index.slim:

ul.fruit
  li Apples
  li Oranges


== partial\
  :'components/date', 
  locals: {day: 1, month: 'Jan', year: 2015}

== partial\
  :'components/date', 
  locals: {day: 25, month: 'Dec', year: 2014}
```

If you are using various kinds of templates, erb, haml, slim, etc., you can set the type when you call partial():

```
partial(:"components/date", :template_engine => :slim, :locals => {...})
```

views/components/_date.slim:

```
#postdate
  .grid
    .grid__cell.day  =day
    .grid__cell.month =month
    .grid__cell.year =year
```

views/layout.slim:

```
doctype html 
html
  head 
    meta charset="utf-8"
    title Test
  body 
    h1 This is the Layout.  Find me in /views/app_layout.slim
    == yield
```

So, I assume you want to do something like this:

routes.rb:

```
get '/' do

  @dates = [
    {day: 1, month: 'Jan', year: 2015},
    {day: 2, month: 'Feb', year: 2015},
    {day: 3, month: 'Mar', year: 2015},
    {day: 4, month: 'Apr', year: 2015},
  ]

  slim :index

end
```

views/index.slim:

```
h2 This is views/index.slim:

ul.fruit
  li Apples
  li Oranges

- @dates.each do |date|
  == partial\
    :'components/date', 
    locals: {day: date[:day], month: date[:month], year: date[:year]}
```

views/components/_date.slim:

```
#postdate
  .grid
    .grid__cell.day  =day
    .grid__cell.month =month
    .grid__cell.year =year
```

...which produces:

## This is the Layout. Find me in /views/app_layout.slim

### This is views/index.slim:

- Apples
- Oranges

1
Jan
2015
2
Feb
2015
3
Mar
2015
4
Apr
2015

Comment: I mean when I call a ==slim :'components/_date' it's there where I can pass in the dates. So my scenario is that I have a list of hardcoded dates for a portfolio, which is where I'm setting my dates.

Comment: *So my scenario is that I have a list of hardcoded dates for a portfolio*  So why can't you hardcode them into your route?  Suppose  you could write:  `==slim :'components_date'('hello', 'world')`  What advantage would that provide over writing the same values in the route?

Comment: The advantage is to render the partial with passed in dates rather than repeating the code in the partial with different dates. I don't think I'm explaining myself very well.

Comment: @liloka, See the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and managed to write a killer partials helper that gives you Rails-like partials functionality. I'm really pleased with it!

```
#partials_helper.rb
module PartialsHelper
  def partial(name, path: '/partials', locals: {})
    Slim::Template.new("#{settings.views}#{path}/#{name}.slim").render(self, locals)
  end
end
```

-

```
#app.rb
require 'slim'
require 'slim/include'
require 'partials_helper'
require 'other_helper_methods'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  helpers do
    include PartialsHelper
    include OtherHelperMethods
  end

  get '/' do
    slim :home
  end
end
```

-

```
#views/home.slim
== partial :_hello_world, locals: { name: 'Andrew' }
```

-

```
#views/partials/_hello_world.slim
h1 Hello, World! Hello #{name}!
```

I initially had only `.render({}, locals)`, which meant that the partials didn't have access to any helper methods contained inside `OtherHelperMethods` (but `home.slim` did). Passing `self` into `.render`, as the first argument, fixes that (if you're curious about that, look up the `Tilt::Template #render` documentation.

With this PartialsHelper, passing locals is optional, as is specifying a different path to the partial (relative to `settings.views`).

Hope you get as much use out of it as I do!